# Mobile Redirect URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm basically trying to make one link on my page and when the user clicks the link it will direct to one of these links depending on what device they are coming from.

So the link says "Download Now" and I need it to launch these URL's depending on the user agent device

```
If Android then android.com
If Windows then windows.microsoft.com
If Apple then  apple.com
```

I am trying to avoid using PHP to accomplish this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried something? Can you show your efforts?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `navigator.userAgent` and created a method to search for android/iPhone/WindowsPhone etc string within the userAgent string. You'll need to research these online and get a list of all mobile devices and redirect based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the User Agent from JavaScript and intercept clicks on links, redirecting to a page depending on what User Agent is detected. Here's some code to give you an idea: [Change link destination based on whether user has mac or PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429058/change-link-destination-based-on-whether-user-has-mac-or-pc). Here's a link to various User Agents which may be useful: [List of User Agents](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php)

Make sure that the link still has a valid href attribute though in case the user disables JavaScript. Another possible approach is modifying all the links: changing the `href` attribute on page load to fit the User Agent.